# Javascript is only validating the first variable and ignoring my others

Tags: javascript, validation

Trying to make an address book for school and entered two fields and having validation. It seems like it's only validating the first field which is the name and ignoring the rest? I'm not sure if I have something wrong? It keeps displaying `not a valid name` as the error message and nothing else.

```
var validate_birthdate = my.isBirthdateBad(add_birthdate);

if (!valid_name.test(add_name)) {
    alert("not a valid name");
    valid_contact = false;
} else if (add_address.length > 0) {
    if (!valid_address.test(add_address)) {
        alert("not a valid address: " + add_address);
        valid_contact = false;
    }
} else if (add_birthdate.length > 0) {
    if (!valid_birthdate.test(add_birthdate)) {
        alert("not a valid birthdate");
        valid_contact = false;
    }
  } else if (add_gender.length > 0) {
      if (!valid_gender.test(add_gender)) {
          alert("not a valid gender");
          valid_contact = false;
      }
    } else if (add_ocupation.length > 0) {
        if (!valid_occupation.test(add_occupation)) {
            alert("not a valid job title");
            valid_contact = false;
        }
} else if (validate_birthdate) {
    alert("not a valid birthdate: " + validate_birthdate);
    valid_contact = false;
} else if (!(add_photo !== undefined) &&
        (add_photo.length > 0) &&
        (add_photo.indexOf("data:image/jpeg") === 0)) {
    alert("image is not a jpeg!");
    valid_contact = false;
}

// note the use of the "anonymous" function
// this returns an array of all of the matched contacts! Powerful!
var exists = _address_book_contacts.filter(function (contact) {

    //check to see if the current "add_name"
    // is found in the address book!
    return contact.name() === add_name;
});

if (exists && (exists.length > 0)) {
    if (!confirm("WARNING: " +
            add_name +
            " exists in database. " +
            "Would you like to add again?")) {
        valid_contact = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `valid_name` and `add_name` in this situation? Add some `console.log()` and show us some output.

Comment: The first "true" `if` branch that is entered *bypasses evaluation* of all associated `else if`/`else` clauses. Since the name is invalid, that branch is entered - and none of the other branches can be executed. Change the `if..else if..` to `if..if..` and you'll get spammed with alerts.

Comment: That is: `if (x) { ONLY_THIS_RUNS } else { OR_ONLY_THIS_RUNS } `; and `if (A) { AX } else if (B) { BX }` is really a short-hand for `if (A) { AX } else { if (B) { BX } }`, where at most *one of* AX/BX can run.

Comment: It sounds like you don't want to use an `if` / `else if` construct since its logic is exclusive (if one condition is true, the other cases will not be tried).

Comment: So should I delete the first if?